# NativeScript: Camera takePicture and upload with nativescript-background-http

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to take a picture with NativeScript Camera module and then upload it with nativescript-background-http (since as I understand this is the only way of uploading in NS at this moment). I'm using iOS simulator, but get an error on Android emulator too.

Camera plugin works fine, takes and saves a picture to a file. However I have a problem to upload the picture from the path after that.

Here is my code:

```
import cameraModule = require('camera')
import imageModule  = require('ui/image')
import enumsModule  = require('ui/enums')
import fsModule     = require('file-system')
import bgHttpModule = require('nativescript-background-http')

const options = { width: 300, height: 300, keepAspectRatio: true }
const format = enumsModule.ImageFormat.jpeg

cameraModule.takePicture(options).then(imageSource => {
    let contentType = `image/${format}` 
    let savePath = fsModule.knownFolders.documents().path
    let fileName = 'img_' + new Date().getTime() + '.' + format
    let filePath = fsModule.path.join( savePath, fileName )

    if ( imageSource.saveToFile( filePath, format ) ) {
        var session = bgHttpModule.session('image-upload')

        var options = {
            url: 'http://192.168.99.100:8003',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                'File-Name': fileName
            },
            description: '{ \'uploading\': ' + fileName + ' }'
        }

        let task = session.uploadFile(filePath, options)

        task.on('progress', logEvent)
        task.on('error', logEvent)
        task.on('complete', logEvent)

        function logEvent(e) {
            console.log(e.eventName)
        }
    }
})
```

The error I get is:

Application error: Error /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/11C75134-AC52-46B8-87F6-58A61B8A1E0C/data/Containers/Data/Applicatio ... 538.jpeg is not a valid file:// url undefined

However if I go to that path the picture with that name is there and valid. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have tested your exact code with the dummy server http://httpbin.org/post and it returned progress and all seems fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get rid of this error by prepending "file://" to the task line

```
var task = session.uploadFile("file://" + this.filePath, request);
```

It works in the emulator but I haven't tested it on an actual device yet.

Comment: This appeared to be an issue with the plugin:https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-background-http/issues/15. And yep, you are right that's what missing.